# Django error filter on ManyToMany relation

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

I would have all message about the request.user
Consider this code:

views.py

```
conversation = MessageConversation.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user.id) | Q(recipient=request.user)).order_by ('-date_create')
```

models.py

```
class MessageConversation(models.Model):
    close = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    user = models.IntegerField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    recipient = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want show all conversations regarding of user connected.If I have more than one entity in the ManyToMany relation the query is multiplied.

Comment: What does "the query is multiplied" means?

Comment: do you mean to say `Q(recipient=request.user)` is evaluating to multiple queries ?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what's not working for you with your example code?  Aside from the fact that you should be using a `ForeignKey` field for `user` rather than an `IntegerField`, and that setting max_length on an `IntegerField` is not valid, your query looks right to me.

Comment: karthikr, yes that's it. For example, if three relation in recipient the same "query" is multiplied by three.

Comment: If your problem is that your query is returning multiple copies of the same `MessageConversation` instance, add `.distinct()` to your query.